# Studying initialization in C++: what does "error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction" means in this case?

Tags: c++, initialization

I am studying initialization in C++. In this proof of concept. I don't understand compiler's advice.
(I already know that declaring a variable inside a cin is not the easy and natural (not even perhaps legal or even apropiate) way. Would be easy to just declare it outside before and no problem. But I asked the question just to understand more deeply what is going on. Trying to understand C++ in a better way and initialization in particular, which is known not to be a trivial subject).

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
        std::cin >> int input_value;
        return 0;
}
```

when trying to compile:

```
 % g++ -Wall -o p44e1 p44e1.cc
p44e1.cc:5:18: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
        std::cin >> int input_value;
                    ~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You need to declare the variable before using it: `int input_value; std::cin >> input_value;`. The compiler misunderstood your intent and gave you a "helpful" message indicating how to cast the (non-existing) variable - which is not what you want to do.

Comment: Unrelated: `int main (void)` isn't needed in C++. Make it `int main()`

Comment: @TedLyngmo But why then the compiler doesn't use something like: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'input_value'`.
What does the message `error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`, means? (So when i encounter it again in another situation, i can know what it means).

Comment: It simply misunderstood what you tried to do. You will not make this mistake many times so I doubt you'll see this message in similar situations many times.

Comment: @nostromo Every programmer has a different style, and compilers vary too. So each programmer tends to see different feedback from the compiler. With time you'll learn about the kind of mistakes you typically make, and how the compiler you use typically responds. It's a learning process, you should not expect the compiler to be so smart that it knows exactly what you have done wrong every time (or even most of the time).

Comment: @nostromo For outright invalid code, compilers tend to generate incomprehensive errors. It just tells you that something starting with std::cin >> int(... could in theory make sense, so it expected ( here. But it's not the only symbol that could make sense, so mentioning it specifically is an arbitrary decision on compiler deverlopers' side.

Comment: What it comes down to ais a common problem with compilers: They have no clue what you really meant to do, so they do the best they can with the description of the program behaviour (the code) you wanted. Sometimes their best isn't that helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function body consists of zero or more *statements*.

There are several kinds of statements. We only care about two here:

- A declaration statement, e.g. `int input_value;`
- An expression statement. That is, `e;`. Where `e` is an expression, meaning "operands connected with operators, or an individual operand".

  `std::cin >> input_value;` would be an expression statement, where `std::cin >> input_value` is an expression (`std::cin` and `input_value` are operands, and `>>` is an operator).

So `std::cin >> int input_value;` is outright invalid. `int input_value;` must be a separate statement, but you tried to embed it into an other (expression) statement.